Controlling PWM with a voltages from synthesizer
I am looking for the simplest PWM oscillator that I can control is Pulse Width with voltages from a synthesizer (outputting between 0V and 5V).
This PWM oscillator should run off a 12V PSU, and its output frequency should be above the audio rate so it won’t be audible.
I found this fastlad simulator online that seems to work, but it uses ±12V to set the PWM manually, and there is no circuit for the triangle wave oscillator that enters the non-inverting pin of the first op-amp.
Edit: Will this circuit using 556 timer will work?
https://tinyurl.com/259s38h6

Have you looked into saw tooth generators and comparators? There are other ways to achieve it too.

is it better to use sawtooth or triangle wave into a comparator for creating the PWM?

I can't say it's better, but it certainly one common way to do it if you want to find examples online. And yes, triangle wave is an option too.
